# Reference books for data visualisation and dashboard design

Tags: resources, info-visualisation, books, dashboard

Please could you recommend some reference texts or other resources concerned with business data visualisation and dashboard design.

There's [Information Dashboard Design by Stephen Few on Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Information-Dashboard-Design-Effective-Communication/dp/0596100167/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1273648805&sr=8-3-fkmr0) but perhaps you can recommended others.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure this book could be useful (despite the fact that it's not about dashboards): [The Visual Display of Quantitative Information](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Visual-Display-Quantitative-Information/dp/0961392142) by Edward Tufte. It's one of my favorite books with lots of examples of information visualizations from different ages and countries.

And take a look at [other Tufte's books](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Edward-R.-Tufte/e/B000APET3Y/), all of them are about data visualization and all are brilliant.

Answer (score 4):

In a [previous discussion](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4896/your-experiences-with-call-centre-wallboard-ux) around this subject Alastair J also recommended Tufte's [Beautiful Evidence](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_be).

I found Stephen Few's book very helpful and easy to read.

I also read a pretty good article on Smashing Magazine about [Bad Infographics](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/10/imagine-a-pie-chart-stomping-on-an-infographic-forever/).

For good examples check out [Infosthetics](http://infosthetics.com/).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above, I recently bought Information Is Beautiful by David McCandless. Haven't had a chance to read it cover to cover yet, but have skimmed it and it has some great data visualisation models.

Answer (score 0):

Not a great example of dashboard design but Brian Suda is currently writing a book '[a Practical Guide to Designing for Data](http://www.designingwithdata.co.uk/)'. Although its not out until later in the year it might be of use for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Information Dashboard Design by Stephen Few is a bit dated, but does a good job of getting the principles across.